# Jessie: v4l2 streaming works with RPi 1B+, but not with 2B or 3B

Tags: raspbian, camera, video, v4l2, cvlc

I just recently upgraded my series of Pi's (1B+, 2B, 3B) to Raspbian Jessie Lite. Now, when I try to setup a stream with my Pi NoIR Camera as I did in Wheezy,

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 --v4l2-width 640 --v4l2-height 480 --v4l2-aspect-ratio 4:3 --v4l2-chroma h264 --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=0.0.0.0:'3564'}'
```

I get the strange result that the stream works with my Pi 1B+ but not with the other two. Whereas CLI output is exactly identical on all Pi's,

```
VLC media player 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (Weatherwax) (revision 2.2.1-0-ga425c42)
[02056228] pulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
[0204ee48] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[01ec68f8] core libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0204ecd8] dbus interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
[0204ecd8] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[01ec68f8] core libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization failed
[0204ef78] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[73b01600] access_output_http access out: Consider passing --http-host=IP on the command line instead.
```

the difference is that I can actually receive a stream from Pi 1B+ but not from 2B or 3B with VLC player running on any other device. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31899307/raspberry-pi-2-v4l2-not-working-with-vlc) has a description that pretty much matches my problem. The problems persists if I insert the Pi 1B+ microSD into the Pi 2B or 3B.

Can somebody help me please? Since I'm running out of good keyword guesses for an internet search, I'm thankful for any hints...